# How to use Views (Month, Day, Week) from Android Stock Calendar in a Custom application

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, android-source

In the Google Stock Android Calendar there exists several Views (Month, Week, Agenda, Week), the source code downloaded from [Google Android Sources Repositories](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/) have the same application, by exploring the code the package named `com.android.calendar` has the main views responsible for rendering these activities :

[image]

with hard working around the code I used two packages `com.android.calendar.month` and `com.android.calendar` but couldn't achieve my goal, this is a sample of what I used:

[image]

and the following code for the main:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

and here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/month"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingTop="1dip"
    android:background="@null">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/month_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/MonthView_MiniMonthLabel" />

    <include android:id="@+id/day_names" layout="@layout/full_month_header" />

     <View
        android:background="@color/calendar_grid_line_inner_vertical_color"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <com.android.calendar.month.MonthListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Till here the code works fine, but the with a blank white screen and an actionbar, if my question was not clear please try to edit it.

```
What should be done to include Calendar Views (Month, Week, Day) in a custom application ?
```

Comment: What do you need to do? Anything more than simply picking a date?

Comment: DID you figure out this issue ?

Comment: @MouhamadLamaa No I haven't till now

Comment: try this it could be the solution, https://github.com/dschuermann/standalone-calendar, i'm working on it now

Comment: @MahmoudHashim if you were able to get this working do share the code im searching for something with the same functionality

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) it is the standard way of integrating calendars in Android.

Also, if you need to select Dates & Time in your UI, there are [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html).

Remember that the default calendar app in android is **open-source**! Feel free to [dig through the code here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar).

Comment: But I meant the View found in the picture

Comment: I see three screenshots containing a lot of different view elements. Which one is the one you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the third picture to the right, how could I achieve this view ? @donfuxx

Comment: It is not _one_ view element, there are many view items that get populated by an Adapter https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/CalendarViewAdapter.java

Answer (score 1):

The screen is blank because you have yet to set an adapter for the ListView. You can see how the adapter is configured in the original Calendar app in [MonthByWeekFragment](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/2b5ddd6c7845ca00f40050941c25f2cc0300b1b1/src/com/android/calendar/month/MonthByWeekFragment.java).

```
    @Override
    protected void setUpAdapter() {
        mFirstDayOfWeek = Utils.getFirstDayOfWeek(mContext);
        mShowWeekNumber = Utils.getShowWeekNumber(mContext);

        HashMap<String, Integer> weekParams = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        weekParams.put(SimpleWeeksAdapter.WEEK_PARAMS_NUM_WEEKS, mNumWeeks);
        weekParams.put(SimpleWeeksAdapter.WEEK_PARAMS_SHOW_WEEK, mShowWeekNumber ? 1 : 0);
        weekParams.put(SimpleWeeksAdapter.WEEK_PARAMS_WEEK_START, mFirstDayOfWeek);
        weekParams.put(MonthByWeekAdapter.WEEK_PARAMS_IS_MINI, mIsMiniMonth ? 1 : 0);
        weekParams.put(SimpleWeeksAdapter.WEEK_PARAMS_JULIAN_DAY,
            Time.getJulianDay(mSelectedDay.toMillis(true), mSelectedDay.gmtoff));
        weekParams.put(SimpleWeeksAdapter.WEEK_PARAMS_DAYS_PER_WEEK, mDaysPerWeek);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new MonthByWeekAdapter(getActivity(), weekParams, mEventDialogHandler);
            mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mObserver);
        } else {
            mAdapter.updateParams(weekParams);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and how the adapter is addded to the ListView in [SimpleDayPickerFragment](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/2b5ddd6c7845ca00f40050941c25f2cc0300b1b1/src/com/android/calendar/month/SimpleDayPickerFragment.java):

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    ...

    setUpAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```